# Cant Deploy Spring Boot on Tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that I am developing. I am using maven to make a war file, so I can deploy on a Tomcat server. On the embedded tomcat the app works perfectly all is working good, but when I deploy the app, although it shows now mistakes when I try to access one of the rest controllers url it shows http 404 error, that the resource could no be located. I am following the steps given on the Spring website. 
This is my pom.xml, where I try both commenting and uncommenting the tomcat dependency.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.designfreed</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-schedule</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>spring-schedule</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!--<dependency>-->
   <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
   <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
   <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
  <!--</dependency>-->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>


</project>
```

I have a little application for testing schedule tasks and I was able to deploy it on a tomcat server. So I dont know if there anything special when deploying an app that has rest controllers. But as I said, when I run the app on the embedded tomcat everything works fine and I get my json response back.

Thanks very much

Comment: How do you deploy it, and which URL gives a 404?

Comment: I have Tomcat running on another pc, and I deploy it like every other war, using the manager from Tomcat. And when I try to do http://localhost:8080/cliente/find/1 thats when I get the error. But when I test that same URL but starting the app from my IDE it works just fine and I get the json response.

Comment: What is the name of the war? Is it ROOT.war? If it's not, then the app is deployed under a context path. So the correct URL is localhost:8080/nameofthewar/cliente/find/1

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That was it! I add the name of the war and now it worked!